# Is there a way to take Javascript and JQuery values and export them to a PDF?

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf

I'm making a quiz application using mostly JQuery with a little JavaScript. At the end of the program, I'm wondering if it's possible to take some of those variables and export the entire thing to a PDF? Is it possible to do at all, or is there some workaround I should be looking into?

Comment: I don't think that it is possible to achieve something like that only with js and jquery. This is something for a backend (php etc.).

Answer (score 3):

You could try https://parall.ax/products/jspdf . It should solve your problem